# How to convert XML response string into dictionary or array?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml, arrays

This is what I get after parsing XML response and appending into string.

Appended string is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xxx.yyyy.in/soap/hubbuch/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:isValidDVNResponse><response>a:10:{s:11:"sso_user_id";s:6:"656451";s:9:"firstname";s:0:"";s:8:"lastname";s:0:"";s:5:"abono";s:0:"";s:4:"hash";s:32:"554457e710839bc3039f6bc81839688e";s:5:"token";s:32:"238e70c6661489bfa6a8a84f2e1aa0f1";s:5:"login";s:23:"x@y.in";s:6:"cookie";s:232:"&lt;img style="width:0px; height:0px;" src="http://xxx.yyyy.in/sso/cookie.php?aktion=set&amp;hash=554457e710839bc3039f6bc81839688e&amp;token=238e70c6661489bfa6a8a84f2e1aa0f1&amp;time=10000&amp;login=x%40y.in&amp;alias=14,15,16" alt="" /&gt;";s:6:"access";a:1:{s:4:"role";s:2:"NO";}s:5:"error";s:0:"";}</response></ns1:isValidDVNResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I get proper dictionary or array from this string? SO that it has key-value pair.

***Note:- a:10 , s:11,... are not needed.***

Thanks..

Comment: The response you posted is not XML but JSON.

Comment: Its look like invalid JSOn

Comment: It was in XML, I have appended in NSString. Also it is not a JSON.

Comment: can you post the xml node for this result?

Comment: @Sunnyshah Yes, I know its not JSON. This string was appended after xml parsing.

Comment: @Sunnyshah Check updated question with complete xml response.

Comment: @Dream Check updated question with complete xml response.

Comment: If it is possible switch to outputting JSON from that service and then use the native JSON serialization tools built into iOS.

Comment: It's called **soap primitive**

Comment: @DearDhruv How to convert Soap Primitive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XML to JSON Dictionary parse to parse all XML data into a Dictionary by using
[XMLDictionary Parser](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary)

A nice project on github which parse all xml data into dictionary.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the value between tags. But actually the value between tags is kind of hash tables . So how can i use it?